# Structure of color critical graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $G$ be a $k$-color critical graph on $N$ vertices. It is a known fact that every vertex of $G$ has at least $k-1$ neighbors (there are more results available on minimum number of edges in color critical graphs). I am curious if something like the following is true:

Let $G$ is a $k$-color critical graph, and complement of $G$ is connected.Then there is a proper $k$-coloring such that there are at least $\frac{N}{k}(1-o(1))$ edges between each pair of color classes.

If the last statement is not true then under what assumption(s) one can ensure that between each pair of color classes there are at least $\frac{N}{k}(1-o(1))$ edges?

Thank you for your help.